# Send Email Notification upon assignment of ticket - ASP.NET MVC C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I would like to notify a user when he/she has been assigned a ticket via mail.
The admin basically has a view of open tickets and a drop down list containing users. Once the Ticket has been assigned, the user should receive a notification in his/her mail box.

I have tried the following but i keep on running into the error:

> Value cannot be null.
> Parameter name: addresses

on the `Mail.To` parameter.

The code responsible for assigning is as below:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> AssignRoles(AssignRolesModel ObjAssign, Registration registration)
{
        try
        {
            if (ObjAssign.ListofUser == null)
            {
                TempData["MessageErrorRoles"] = "No Tickets to assign";
                ObjAssign.ListofAdmins = _IAssignRoles.ListofAdmins();
                ObjAssign.ListofUser = _IAssignRoles.ListofUser();
                return View(ObjAssign);
            }

            var SelectedCount = (from User in ObjAssign.ListofUser
                                 where User.SelectedUsers == true
                                 select User).Count();

            if (SelectedCount == 0)
            {
                TempData["MessageErrorRoles"] = "You have not Selected any Ticket to Assign";
                ObjAssign.ListofAdmins = _IAssignRoles.ListofAdmins();
                ObjAssign.ListofUser = _IAssignRoles.GetListofUnAssignedUsers();
                return View(ObjAssign);
            }

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                ObjAssign.CreatedBy = Convert.ToInt32(Session["SuperAdmin"]);
                _IAssignRoles.SaveAssignedRoles(ObjAssign);
            }

            ObjAssign = new AssignRolesModel
            {
                ListofAdmins = _IAssignRoles.ListofAdmins(),
                ListofUser = _IAssignRoles.GetListofUnAssignedUsers()
            };

            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
            mail.To.Add(registration.EmailID);
            mail.Subject = "Help Desk";
            mail.IsBodyHtml = true;

            using (var smtp = new SmtpClient())
            {
                await smtp.SendMailAsync(mail);
                smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            }

            TempData["MessageRoles"] = "Ticket Assigned Successfully!";

            return RedirectToAction("AssignRoles");
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
}
```

I make use of interfaces, so below is the code for `SaveAssignedRoles`:

```
public bool SaveAssignedRoles(AssignRolesModel AssignRolesModel)
{
        bool result;

        try
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < AssignRolesModel.ListofUser.Count(); i++)
            {
                if (AssignRolesModel.ListofUser[i].SelectedUsers)
                {
                    AssignedRoles AssignedRoles = new AssignedRoles
                    {
                        AssignedRolesID = 0,
                        AssignToAdmin = AssignRolesModel.RegistrationID,
                        CreatedOn = DateTime.Now,
                        CreatedBy = AssignRolesModel.CreatedBy,
                        Status = "A",
                        RegistrationID = AssignRolesModel.ListofUser[i].RegistrationID,
                       // RegID = AssignRolesModel.ListofAdmins[i].RegistrationID
                    };

                    DB.AssignedRoles.Add(AssignedRoles);
                    DB.SaveChanges();
                }
            }

            result = true;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }

        return result;
}
```

Comment: I think you might need to "new up" Mail.To before using? Or just pass the mailadress to the MailMessage ctor directly. And make sure that registration.Email is not null.

Comment: So look at the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.mailaddresscollection.add?view=netcore-3.1) and debug your code; `registration.EmailID` is `null`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that registration.Email is not null/empty.

Also, I think that you can pass the email directly to the MailMessage ctor like this.

```
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(registration.EmailID))
{
     var email = new MailMessage(from, registration.EmailID);
}
```

Or if you want to stick to your code:

```
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(registration.EmailID))
{
    MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
    mail.To.Add(registration.EmailID);
}
```

Comment: The code you provided is good. It solves the issue of null email id but it doesn't solve the main issue of sending the notification to the user selected

Comment: I am receiving an alert "ticket successfully assigned" but no ticket has been dispatched.

Comment: Well you still not give us enough information. You don't get any exceptions? Can you show us your smtp config?

Comment: The issue is resulting from this field  `mail.To.Add(registration.EmailID);` if i replace it with an actual email, it is successful, otherwise no action is run. No exception is encountered at all either

Comment: Well then you have a validation issue, right? If you allow users to input invalid emails it will not work, simple as that. Add validation and be done with it :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219192/discussion-between-nickson-and-joseftw).